# What is the the difference between these reference copying in the JAVA?

Tags: java, reference, deep-copy, recurrence, shallow-copy

I've got a question which are these - What is the difference between these two types of passing the references in the base condition of the recursive function BT()? (Mentioned in the comments of the base condition ).

1. https://ideone.com/rJP0Qv

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
 
        BT(res,temp,1,4,2);
        System.out.print(res);
    }
 
    public static void BT(List<List<Integer>> res,List<Integer> temp,int start , int n , int k ){
 
        if(temp.size()==k){
            res.add(temp);  // here we are just directly passing the temp refrence.
            return;
        }
 
        for(int i=start;i<=n;i++){
            temp.add(i);
            BT(res,temp,i+1,n,k);
            System.out.println("Temp "+temp);
            temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
 
        }
    }
}
```

2. https://ideone.com/UtXsJa

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
 
        BT(res,temp,1,4,2);
        System.out.print(res);
    }
 
    public static void BT(List<List<Integer>> res,List<Integer> temp,int start , int n , int k ){
 
        if(temp.size()==k){
            res.add(new ArrayList(temp));  // here we are passing a new object in which temp reference is passed
            return;
        }
 
        for(int i=start;i<=n;i++){
            temp.add(i);
            BT(res,temp,i+1,n,k);
            System.out.println("Temp "+temp);
            temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
 
        }
    }
}
```

3. Which of the above two links is having a shallow copy and a deep copy of temp list in the base condition?
4. Is it because since we are directly passing the reference temp in the 1st link (https://ideone.com/MuLzLb ) whatever is the last change that we've made in the temp will be visible in all of the result added in List<List> res   i.e.  [[], [], [], [], [], []] since temp will be an empty list at the end of the last recursive call?
5. And how to decide when to use a deep copy or the shallow copy of the reference in recurrence functions?

Answer (score 0):

3.res.add(temp);  ---> Shallow copy
res.add(new ArrayList(temp));  ---> deep copy

4.The reason why your first code snippet gives you empty output is because you're just adding the reference in List of List (List<List> res)and then you are removing the objects from the reference(temp) as well.So at the end temp will have not values and so the list of lists will have no values.

[image]

So as given in the image
lets assume temp has [3,7,9] and when you are adding the temp only its reference will be passed, not a copy.Now [3,7,9] will have 2 references.One is temp and another is in List of List.
so whenever you do any changes in temp it'll be reflected in the List<List> res.

5.There is no hard and fast rule defined for selecting between shallow copy and deep copy but normally we should keep in mind that if an **object has only primitive fields**, then obviously we should go for **shallow copy**, but if the object has **references** to other objects, then based on the requirement, shallow copy or deep copy should be done. If the **references are not modified** then there is no point to initiate a **deep copy**.

Note : Your Back-tracking algorithm involves adding and removing of values in a list in order to get different types of combination as result.So whenever you are adding or removing values from an reference you should make a copy of it(as done in 2nd snippet) and store it in List of Lists.

Comment: Thank you @Akash R for such a well detailed explanation of my quries.